# How to keep PHP session set only when a function is called?

Tags: php, session

I have this class (I have same code for another question but that's for another subject), this works fine, I create a Sesiones object and then call IniciarSesion function when I want to start a new session, but unless I put session_start(); outside my Sesiones class, session won't be maintained. I'm intending on blocking access to pages when $_SESSION is not set, but If I include it outside my class session will always be set, so what would be the best approach for what I want?

```
session_start();//Here it works on all pages but not desired behavior
class Sesiones {

    public function IniciarSesion($params, $url = NULL) {
        //session_start(); Where it originally was but It doesn't work on other files
        //Iterar parametros de array params y setearlo en session
        foreach ($params as $param){
            $_SESSION[$param["param"]] = $param["val"];
        }
        //URL para redireccionar
        if (isset($url)) {
            header("Location: " . $url);
        }
    }
    public function CerrarSesion($url = NULL) {
        session_destroy();
        exit();
        //El parametro URL es para saber a que URL redireccionar
        if (isset($url)) {
            header("Location: " . $url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily matter where `session_start()` occurs, so long as it is before *anything* is output to the browser because sessions rely on Cookies, Cookies rely on HTTP headers, and HTTP headers must be sent in their entirety before page content. This means that one or [if not *the*] very first things you need to do in your application is instantiate a `Sesiones` object and call `IniciarSesion()`.

Comment: Checking for an active session is a bit broad. Why not set a value in the session for those that have access and check that this value exists in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser ( that's a thing you should keep in your mind). In your code I see no need to call session_start within the class. However it's not going to work.

Comment: session_start() won't work inside the class or this whole code?